# Share location javascript trigger html5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, geolocation

So I'm using the demo code at https://github.com/remy/html5demos/blob/master/demos/geo.html and I want to change a div class when the user clicks on 'Share location' in the browser.

Is there a trigger or function available for that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you don't want to use the success callback of the getCurrentPosition() method, because it will only be called once a location has been determined.
Why don't you try the watchPosition method instead?

```
if(!!navigator.geolocation) {
  var id = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(success, error, options);
  if(id)
    //change the div class
  else
    //too bad, no permission
} else
  //geo not supported
```

Comment: As far as I know, watchPosition only detects when the location of the user has changed from a previous position. Im looking more for a trigger on the browser function.